# PHP calculate date range from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I use service API which provide a schedule in json in format describes date ranges:

```
.... // Other items
{
  "registration": "SP-TEST",
  "records": [
    {
      "from": "2014-12-06T13:40Z",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "from": "2014-12-07T14:30Z",
      "available": false
    },
    {
      "from": "2014-12-13T14:30Z",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "from": "2014-12-13T16:30Z",
      "available": false
    },
    {
      "from": "2014-12-15T14:30Z",
      "available": true
    }
  ]
},
....
```

But it uncomfortable for use and search. I need import it to MySQL DB and perform search in date range where is available, so I need combine arrays something like:

```
[{
  "registration": "SP-TEST",
  "from": "2014-12-06T13:40Z",
  "to": "2014-12-07T14:30Z"
},
{
  "registration": "SP-TEST",
  "from": "2014-12-13T14:30Z",
  "to": "2014-12-13T16:30Z"
},
{
  "registration": "SP-TEST",
  "from": "2014-06-06T13:40Z",
  "to": "2014-06-07T14:30Z"
},
{
  "registration": "SP-TEST",
  "from": "2014-12-15T14:30Z",
  "to": "2014-02-07T14:30Z"
}]
```

I use usort function to sort by time source array (json_decode($schedule)):

```
usort($schedule->records, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->from) - strtotime($b->from);
 });
```

So, if this code is correct I can use foreach to populate new array, but it does not work, because a little problem: "records" can contain just one record. It can have "available": true or "available": false, which means that it available or not from current date up 2 month.

Maybe somebody prompts me a right way?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Sort by date, then foreach.

```
function schedule($records) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // 0 timezone

    $result = array();

    foreach ($records as $k => $v) {
        $record = array_merge($record, array(
            'available' => $v->available,
            'location' => $v->location,
            'from' => $v->from,
            'depart' => '',
            'arrive' => '',
            'to'=>   date("Y-m-d\TH:i\Z", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime($v->from)))
        ));

        if (count($records) > 1) {
            $record['to'] = date("Y-m-d\TH:i\Z", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime($record['from'])));
        }
        if (isset($records[$k+1])) {
            $record['to'] = $records[$k+1]->from;
            $record['depart'] = $v->location;
            $record['arrive'] = $records[$k+1]->location;
        }
        $result[] = $record;
    }

    return $result;
}
```